# Is there a cloud service that allows waking up a VM/container on an incoming TCP connection?

Tags: paas, iaas

I would like to host a network server that handles requests in short bursts. It only needs to run infrequently, while clients are connected to it. Keeping the VM up 24/7 in case a client connects is wasteful.

Is there a service on a public cloud provider (e.g. AWS, GCP, Azure, etc.) that can be configured to wake up / start a VM (or some form of container instance with user binaries), when there is an incoming TCP connection on a certain port?

There exist cloud services that will fire up containers or virtual machines on-demand, when certain events occur (objects created, message queues, REST API call, http/https access). But, I can't find anything for handling generic TCP connection network events.

**Use cases:**

- a low-traffic mail server, which would only need to perform work when a client connects over IMAP, or when there is incoming mail over SMTP.
- a development VM that resumes when a developer connects over SSH.

I'd prefer an AWS recipe, but maybe there are options in other cloud providers. Maybe some sort of load-balancing service? I'm willing to pay a small latency penalty of a few seconds for waking it up.

Comment: Are you interested in VMs generally or cloud services specifically? Can you narrow your question to focus on the service or host or container platform you intend to actually use?

Comment: I'm coming from an AWS perspective, but I'm not set on any platform in particular. I'm looking for something like AppEngine, where you pay only while it runs, except I'd like the app/container/VM to start not just when an http/https request comes in. any tcp request.

Comment: Maybe this is a degenerate case of load-balancing. where the service goes form 0 instances (most of the time) to 1.

Comment: Why not just use https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/12/13/amazon-simple-email-service-gets-simpler-with-smtp/ ? What conditions require that you run your own mailserver in an instance/container/VM in the cloud but cannot use a simple cloud based SMTP service directly?

Comment: Simple email service is for outgoing mail only, afaik. And mail server was just an example. Other examples: ftp, dedicated game servers (where VM spins up when first player joins, VM shuts down when last player in party leaves).

Answer (score 1):

If you control the client side's code, you can split the interaction to two parts. The first one sends a request to an HTTP endpoint backed by a lambda function. The function will spin up the VM/container and reply to the client with the Server's address. From there, the client can continue as normal.

As you only pay for the HTTP endpoint per actual invocation, you are not paying anything while it is not used.

Alternatively, it is possible to create an AWS auto scaling group with a minimum of zero instances and a maximum of 1. Since you will have zero instances some of the time, the metric you monitor for auto scaling can't be based on the EC2 instances. So you need an AWS Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) in front of your auto scaling group. The ELB publishes metrics to AWS CloudWatch, and your scaling group should use those metrics using a dynamic scaling policy.

At this point, you should ask yourself if just keeping a single nano instance running 24x7 is not both cheaper and easier - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/introducing-t2-nano-the-smallest-lowest-cost-amazon-ec2-instance/

Comment: That's nice. But I don't control the client code (e.g. other mailservers sending me mail, ssh clients). I'll have to check on the ELB stuff:  with that setup, would the client's TCP flow end up being funnelled through the front end of the load balancer, or would the connection request appear to hang until the service is up, and then TCP flow redirected to the new VM?

Comment: Re: nano: assuming the service can run within the resource constraints of the nano, that's a nice option. If not, then I guess the nano could spin up a larger VM on demand, but then client flows would need to be proxied through it.